# Create a global validation rule with aurelia-validation

Tags: validation, aurelia

I have code like this:

```
import {ValidationRules} from 'aurleia-validation'

export class EmailDialog{
    email = null

    activate(item){
       email = item
       ValidationRules.ensure(i => i.emailAddress)
           .required()
           .email()
       ... // other code
    }
```

I want to add a new `.email()` validation function that either overrides the existing one or just has a new name (i.e `.emailExp()`) that is available anywhere in my app that I use ValidationRules.

I have seen code that enables you to add custom rules like so:

```
ValidationRules.customRule('emailExp',(value,obj) => {},"")
```

which you can then call with

```
ValidationRules.ensure(i => i.emailAddress).satisfiesRule('emailExp')
```

However, I'm not sure where to put that code to make it available globally.  Do I simply add the custom rules in the app.js?  Will this make the custom rules available to any VM that imports ValidationRules?

Is there a way to extend the fluid API of ValidationRules so that I could do the following:

```
ValidationRules.ensure(i => i.emailAddress).emailExp()
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to put it in `app.js` in the constructor.  By putting it here, it will be available globally.

You can follow this example from my application:

```
import { ValidationRules } from 'aurelia-validation';

export class App {

  constructor() {
    ValidationRules.customRule(
      'integerRange',
      (value, obj, min, max) => value === null || value === undefined
        || Number.isInteger(1 * value) && value >= min && value <= max,
      null,
      (min, max) => ({ min, max })
    );
  }
}
```

Usage (in any viewmodel):

```
ValidationRules
  .ensure('cat_value_orig').required().maxLength(255)
  .ensure('cat_value_tran').minLength(2).maxLength(255)
  .ensure('cat_order').satisfiesRule('integerRange', 0, 100)
  .on(this);
```

Comment: Would it be possible or advisable to put it into the globalResources?

Comment: `globalResources` is only for custom elements, custom attributes, value converters and binding behaviors.  It won't work to put other things there.

Comment: That's too bad. Putting reusable customRules in app.js makes them less re-usable across projects. There must be a better way.

Comment: You can always put your custom rules in another file and import it in `app.js` or another location to ensure it gets loaded at the beginning of your app. Then you could reuse the same file in another application.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, is to create a file for each custom validation, and then register in `main.ts`.

1) Create a file for your validation, i suggest the following path: `resources/custom-validations`

```
import { ValidationRules } from "aurelia-validation";

function registerCustomRule() {
    ValidationRules.customRule(
      'integerRange',
      (value, obj, min, max) => value === null || value === undefined
        || Number.isInteger(1 * value) && value >= min && value <= max,
      null,
      (min, max) => ({ min, max })
    );
}

export default registerCustomRule();
```

2) Inside the path you crete the validation, create another file to register the validations, `resources/custom-validations/index.ts`

```
import './integer-range-validation'; //<--- file created in step 1
import { FrameworkConfiguration } from 'aurelia-framework';
export function configure(config: FrameworkConfiguration) {
}
```

3) In `main.ts` you tell aurelia to use your path

```
aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .plugin('aurelia-validation')
    .feature('extensions')
    .feature('resources/custom-validations')
    .feature('resources');
```